# self_url() shows incorrect value when using Apache load balancer and PlackUp

Tags: perl, apache-2.2

Apache proxies to a PSGI application using HTTP::Server::PSGI.

apache conf file:

```
<Proxy balancer://my_cluster>
   BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
   BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
   BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3003
</Proxy>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /dispatch/ balancer://my_cluster/
```

The url is going to be:
    http://foo.com/dispatch/main

after calling $self->query->self_url() I get:
    http://foo.com/main

/dispatch is cut out every time.  I'm not sure what layer is cutting it out or how to get it back.

Comment: Does your PSGI app use the `ReverseProxy` middleware?

Comment: No.  Should it? (15 char comment min?)

Comment: turned out to be a red herring, per discussion in `#plack`. Ideally, Middleware::ReverseProxy would help with this, but there's no "forwarded path" information, so it actually doesn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I needed to set ProxyPreserveHost Off (which is the default)

Change the entry point for the PSGI app.

```
builder {
   return $app;
}
```

becomes:

```
builder {
   mount "/dispatch" => $app
}
```

change the ProxyPass to:

```
ProxyPass /dispatch/ balancer://my_cluster/dispatch/
```

Now url_self() works as expected.